# access an array from another class

Tags: firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

[image: photo album]

what i want to do here is when i access the first album by pressing on the picture i should get pictures from firebase for that specific album but i have a problem with that and here is my code.

```
class albumsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var posts = [Post]()
    static var imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self


    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS3.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot {
                print ("SNAP: \(snap)")

                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key , postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    })

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as? collectionViewCellAlbums {

        if let img = albumsVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.mainImg as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(post: post, img: img)
            return cell

        }else {

            cell.configureCell(post: post)
            return cell
        }
    }
    else {
        return collectionViewCellAlbums()
    }


    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAlbum", sender: self)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {

    /**
    if segue.identifier == "showAlbum"
    {

        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
        let vc = segue.destination as! newViewController
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        if let img = CollectionVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
            vc.image = img
    }
}
*/


}

}
```

I don't know how to access the array in the second class as shown in the picture for this function    override func prepare(for segue

the class for the second array is exactly the same as the first one except the `newViewController.swift`

```
class newViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

       var image = UIImage()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       self.imageView.image = self.image

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In class `collectionVC` you should have variable :
 `imageList`

and in   `albumVC`  at:
`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`
after
`let vc = segue.destination as! newViewController`
set :

```
vc.imageList = self.post.getAllImageOfPost()
```

Comment: but this has nothing to do with the collection view and if you look at the picture above i used newViewController to view the image in full screen so how can i use the same class for the one in the middle which is called CollectionVC and what type of variables should i have

Answer (score 0):

In such cases using a singleton class solves the problem. In Singleton pattern you create instance just-in-time. This means when you set an array for example, this array will be allocated in memory until the program finishes running.

Refer to this link for Singleton implementation:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/